# Android check has telephone call active

Tags: android, phone-call

How to check if a telephone call is currently active from a non-telephone app?

What API do I need to detect this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

try this:

```
public boolean isCallActive(Context context){
   AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   return manager.getMode() == AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL;
}
```

Comment: I would really prefer `return manager.getMode()==AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL;` the rest is perfect, thanks!

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you. +1

Comment: Nice!, to reduce code i would simply write: `return manager.getMode() == AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)`

Comment: Just as a note, this doesn't work in call cases. If I have a call active and another waiting, I finish the call active and answer the one waiting, this won't say there was a period of time with no call active (after I finish the active one and before I answer the waiting one). It's always MODE_IN_CALL since the moment one call gets the phone to CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK until the phone goes to CALL_STATE_IDLE, no matter if I didn't answer the waiting call at all or not. Pity.